# Is there some function of $n$ that is a multiple of $\phi(n^2)$?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, prime-numbers, number-theory

Not sure which forum to post this question so [here is a link to it from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207565/is-there-some-function-of-n-that-is-a-multiply-of-phin2).

This is to adapt the approach of Fermat's Little Theorem to the Paillier encryption system.

I understand that this will occasionally fail (approximately 1 in $\sqrt n$), but I feel this is unlikely enough to ignore.  Am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: I'm admittedly a bit confused. Do you want an answer to the same question as asked on Math.SE here or do you want an answer to the stated question asking whether $1$ in $\sqrt n$ can reasonably be considered to be small enough to ignore?

Comment: both really. because it's been shown to be insecure I going to have to look for another approach but I'm still interested if $1$ in $\sqrt n$ is small enough to ignore. thanks

Comment: OK, I suggest the following way forward then: This question will receive an answer on whether the considered error probability is small enough to ignore and the linked Math.SE answer stays for context (or is migrated here to Crypto.SE) so we don't have to essentially copy & paste poncho's Math.SE answer somewhere.

Comment: The first question is in the title, and the second "question" is elliptical.  Both, I take it, appear on two SE sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that this will occasionally fail (approximately $1$ in $\sqrt n$) but I feel this is unlikely enough to ignore?

Yes. From the context it seems that $n$ is supposed to be difficult to factor. This puts it in the range of $2048$-bit length and more, i.e. $n\approx 2^{2048}$. For this kind of number, $\sqrt n$ becomes $\approx 2^{1024}$ and $1/2^{1024}$ is small enough to safely be ignored. As a related example: It is *ridiculously* more likely to guess a random 256-bit AES key first try than to hit a $1/2^{1024}$ chance.

For a more theoretical treatment: $1$ in $\sqrt n$ belongs to what cryptographers call a *negligible function* which is the common measure used to gauge whether it's acceptable for an *intelligent* adversary to have this kind of success probability (with negligible function in the bit length of the secret = secure).